# Normalizing User Input - to do a text match in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to allow a user to input text in a textarea. Their input saves to the DB like so:

```
--\r\nHello World\r\nI see stars\r\n\r\nVisit My Website: www.website.com
```

Problem is I'm trying to find that inside of a parsed email. While it looks the same when rendered. It's being stored differently and I don't have control over that. The text looks like:

```
--\nHello World\nI see stars\n\nVisit My Website: www.website.com\n\n
```

While these both render the same, they are stored differently which causes this to fail:

```
email.sub(useinput, '').strip
```

Thoughts? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: is that really a reason to downvote this question?

Comment: Can you change your regex in `useinput` to use `\s+` for whitespace, rather than hardcoding `\n` or `\r\n`?

Comment: IDK, right now it's a textarea in rails that posts straight to the DB is that possible?

Comment: @matt b: When someone's using bad English out of rudeness, rather than because they speak it as a second language? Yes!

Comment: @steenslag, this is a very different problem.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, "TEXTAREA" instead of "textarea" is not actually bad grammar. Regardless, it's minor, and has nothing to do with the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text1 = "--\r\nHello World\r\nI see stars\r\n\r\nVisit My Website: www.website.com"
text1_modified = text1.gsub("\r\n", "\n")
text2 = "--\nHello World\nI see stars\n\nVisit My Website: www.website.com\n\n"
text2.sub(text1_modified, '').strip
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, That works. The big challenge with fixing this was sometimes the email client includes \r\n in between paragraphs and sometimes it doesn't. I ended up getting this to work by always running the gsub like you have above whether it applies or not as it doesn't break anything